# Use RegEx to match URL

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex to pull a URL out of an auto-generated email from my monitoring system. For example:

```
https://mon.contoso.com/mon/call.py?fn=edit&num=1389896156
```

I need a regex to match:

```
https://mon.contoso.com/mon/call.py?fn=edit&num=XXXXXXXXX
```

whereby the "x"'s always change. I run into an issue with the "?". The point of this is to append the URL to a field in JIRA.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("https://mon.contoso.com/mon/call.py?fn=edit&num=(\d+)")
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputEmail);
return m.matches() ? m.group(1) : "";
```

This returns num if it is numeric, otherwise you might want to use `\w` instead of `\d`. If you want the whole URL, remove the group() parameter.

Comment: Why use a look behind? You could put the capture group on the digits instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate what language you're working in.

In Python and JavaScript, this regex will identify a variety of URLs:

```js
/\[[^\]\n]+\](?:\([^\)\n]+\)|\[[^\]\n]+\])|(?:\/\w+\/|.:\\|\w*:\/\/|\.+\/[./\w\d]+|(?:\w+\.\w+){2,})[./\w\d:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=\-~%]*/gi
```

You can refer to this [regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/iY9zJ1/1) for examples of the regex in use.

[image]

#### Explanation:

```
/\[[^\]\n]+\](?:\([^\)\n]+\)|\[[^\]\n]+\])|(?:\/\w+\/|.:\\|\w*:\/\/|\.+\/[./\w\d]+|(?:\w+\.\w+){2,})[./\w\d:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=\-~%]*/gi
    1st Alternative: \[[^\]\n]+\](?:\([^\)\n]+\)|\[[^\]\n]+\])
        \[ matches the character [ literally
        [^\]\n]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \] matches the character ] literally
            \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
        \] matches the character ] literally
        (?:\([^\)\n]+\)|\[[^\]\n]+\]) Non-capturing group
            1st Alternative: \([^\)\n]+\)
                \( matches the character ( literally
                [^\)\n]+ match a single character not present in the list below
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                    \) matches the character ) literally
                    \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
                \) matches the character ) literally
            2nd Alternative: \[[^\]\n]+\]
                \[ matches the character [ literally
                [^\]\n]+ match a single character not present in the list below
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                    \] matches the character ] literally
                    \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
                \] matches the character ] literally
    2nd Alternative: (?:\/\w+\/|.:\\|\w*:\/\/|\.+\/[./\w\d]+|(?:\w+\.\w+){2,})[./\w\d:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=\-~%]*
        (?:\/\w+\/|.:\\|\w*:\/\/|\.+\/[./\w\d]+|(?:\w+\.\w+){2,}) Non-capturing group
            1st Alternative: \/\w+\/
                \/ matches the character / literally
                \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                \/ matches the character / literally
            2nd Alternative: .:\\
                . matches any character (except newline)
                : matches the character : literally
                \\ matches the character \ literally
            3rd Alternative: \w*:\/\/
                \w* match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                : matches the character : literally
                \/ matches the character / literally
                \/ matches the character / literally
            4th Alternative: \.+\/[./\w\d]+
                \.+ matches the character . literally
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                \/ matches the character / literally
                [./\w\d]+ match a single character present in the list below
                    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                    ./ a single character in the list ./ literally
                    \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                    \d match a digit [0-9]
            5th Alternative: (?:\w+\.\w+){2,}
                (?:\w+\.\w+){2,} Non-capturing group
                    Quantifier: {2,} Between 2 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                    \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
                    \. matches the character . literally
                    \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        [./\w\d:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=\-~%]* match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            ./ a single character in the list ./ literally
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            \d match a digit [0-9]
            :/?# a single character in the list :/?# literally
            \[ matches the character [ literally
            \] matches the character ] literally
            @!$&'()*+,;= a single character in the list @!$&'()*+,;= literally (case insensitive)
            \- matches the character - literally
            ~% a single character in the list ~% literally
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```